# How to change the machine name of the content type in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I found an annoying typo in the machine name of one of the content types, and I'd like to fix it. The only way I know is to delete the content type, and create a fresh one, but there is a plenty of fields in that content type that I don't want to recreate.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I know this question is for Drupal 7. There is a way to do this for Drupal 8 here, I haven't tried it yet, but since this answer is the top result for a search I figured I would post it https://medium.com/@philw_/how-to-change-a-content-type-s-machine-name-in-drupal-8-33fc3c0520dc.

Comment: Also possibility of using Entity Clone for Drupal 8. https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to structure, click content types, click edit next to the content type you want to edit. Click edit next to the machine name and change it to the name you want.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

If you merely want to change the administrative name, then change that instead.

Comment: Oh, didn't think it's so easy :)

Comment: Careful, it's not always so easy. I've had data loss doing this, most modules don't play nice if they've stored configs using the machine name. I'd only do this if I had a backup, just in case.

Comment: Ensure to flush your cache after making the change.

Comment: I don't see a link to edit machine name in the latest D7. Has it gone (or does it require a module)?

Comment: Can't see either (on different admin themes)

Comment: You will only see the 'edit' button if your content type is not stored in a 'feature' :)

Answer (score 0):

If the name is unique (it probably is if it contains a typo), change all occurrences of the name in the database (including table names) and clear the cache.

In D6 the table `node_type` contains content type machine name definitions. Those names are also used in tables with the prefix `content_type_`. If the content types aren't used anywhere else, changing the entry and the table name should do it. It's possible that those names have changed in D7.